# python packaging problem

Tags: python, package

hi develop code in python to scan wifi and send to the server, its working fine when execute manually, but i packaged it via http://www.python-packager.com by uploading my .py file and they create package for me as deb file for linux, and  i download it and install the package but nothing happen when i click the .exe or set it as startup application,

why this happen, nothing is printed in the terminal

in .py file i'm having print statement to check manually to list out the wifi scan value, data to post to the server, response from the server once send

how this can be solve

thanks

Comment: How can you have a .exe when you've packaged it as a deb file?

Comment: That site looks experimental and does too much. If I am interested in your module standard distutils http://docs.python.org/distutils/introduction.html and the Python Package Index http://pypi.python.org/pypi are better vehicles for getting your code out. In particular, I don't want a .deb file that smashes my Python installation when all I want is your module and already have an execution environment.

Comment: the exe means executable (application/x-executable), this is shown when i right click the file and choose properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How this can be solved?"

Use a standard packager.  Read this: http://docs.python.org/distutils/introduction.html and this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip and this: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout

Answer (score 4):

I'm the maintainer of the project, I thought I'd chime in and give my 2c.

I had a look at your program. With .deb's, it installs everything to /opt/application-name. So to debug-it, run it from the command line. eg. "/opt/Jemapoh_Wifi/Jemapoh_Wifi".

I just ran it myself and your programs gives the error "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/Jemapoh_Wifi/config.txt'". So your program's looking for config.txt but you didn't upload it with the program. :-)

If you have any further problems, please email me or report a bug on Launchpad - http://launchpad.net/python-packager. There'll be a re-vamped version coming out soon, hopefully it'll make things easier to understand.

Hope that helps/makes sense.

Cheers,
Jackson

Comment: Hi Jackson, thanks 4 ur reply, yes its using config.txt, when i use python-packager site, its only asking to upload .py file, how to upload the config.txt

then i already manually add the config.txt into /opt/Jemapoh_Wifi and already try run in cmd line as u mention but nothing is happen,

i also try to add as startup application, but nothing happen also

thanks

Comment: You can upload a .py file, a .zip file, a .tar or .tar.gz file to the site. Try making a zip file and put 2 files in it. The config.txt and the Python file for your program. And where it has "Upload Source", upload the zip file with the two files in it. Hope that helps!